# Show specific running time in Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I've tried looking this up almost everywhere and still no luck..

I've been able to create a live running clock in PowerPoint but is there a way where I can make it a specific time? Ex. I want the time to start at 2:20:00 PM although that may not be the current time and have it run?

Currently I'm using

```
Public clock as Boolean

Public currenttime, currentday as string

Sub Pause()
Dim PauseTime, start
PauseTime = 1
start = Timer
Do While Timer < start + PauseTime
DoEvents 
Loop 
End Sub

Sub StartClock()
clock = Time
Do Until clock = false
On Error Resume Next
currentime = Format ((Now()), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
currentime = Mid(currenttime, 1, Len(currenttime) - 3)
ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition).Shapes("TimeTest").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = currenttime
Pause
Loop 
End Sub

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal objWindows As SlideShowWindow)
clock = false
ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition).Shapes("TimeTest").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "--:--:--"
End Sub

Sub OnSlideShowTerminate()
clock = false
End Sub
```

I found this on a YouTube video I had watched and it was successful showing the currenttime but now how would I alter it to show a specific time?

Comment: If you post the code you've used to implement your clock or at least explain how you've done it, someone may be able to help. Otherwise, everyone would just be guessing.

Comment: Thank you, I have gone back and edited my original post so it now shows the code that I used.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Currentime = format("2:20 PM","hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

Use that in place of the existing two Currentime= lines